# Returning a while loop from an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, while-loop

I'm trying to return a while loop from an AJAX request, whilst also returning other data.

Basically i'm currently returning 3 or 4 sets of data from php requests, and passing them into my application on return. But I need to be able to loop through one of the sets of data to print to a table.

All of my code is working, i'm not getting any errors, its just not returning my devices array correctly.

I'm very close, and I think I know what my problem is, i just cant think at the moment how to solve it.

**Javascript**

```
function getDataViaAjax(id, days) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/processes/getWebsiteStatsData.php', // URL of php command
        type: 'POST', //TYPE
        data: {'id': id, 'days': days}, //Variables in JSON FORMAT
        success: function(results) {
            //SUCCESSFUL REQUEST FUNCTION
            var result = $.parseJSON(results);
            document.getElementById("websiteStatisticsDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.querySelector("#websiteStatisticsURL > strong").innerHTML = result.dataArray.url;
            document.querySelector("#websiteStatisticsBounceRate").innerHTML = result.dataArray.bounceRate;
            document.querySelector("#websiteStatisticsDiv > div > div.col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.left > div > div").style.width = result.dataArray.bounceRate;
            document.getElementById("websiteStatisticsConversionRate").innerHTML = result.dataArray.conversionRate;
            document.querySelector("#websiteStatisticsDiv > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div").style.width = result.dataArray.conversionRate;
            var arrayLength = result.phonesArray.device.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                document.getElementById("arrayTest").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result.phonesArray.device);
            }
        }
    }); // end ajax call
};
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include "../includes/includes.php";
$id = $_POST['id'];
$conversionRateDays = $_POST['days'];

$getSites = $db->query_assoc("SQL QUERY GOES HERE");
$getBounceRate = $db->query_assoc("SQL QUERY GOES HERE");
$getConversionRate = $db->query_assoc("SQL QUERY GOES HERE")
$getPhoneResults = $db->query_assoc("SQL QUERY GOES HERE");

$url = $getSites['main_url'];
$bounceRate = $getBounceRate['result'];
$conversionRate = $getConversionRate['result'];
$dataArray = array('url' => $url,'bounceRate' => $bounceRate, 'conversionRate' => $conversionRate);
$results = array('dataArray' => $dataArray, 'phonesArray' => $getPhoneResults);
echo json_encode($results, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

At the moment if I run

```
console.log(result.phonesArray.device);
```

it only returns my first row of the database, but if I run it in a for loop like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    console.log(result.phonesArray.device[i]);
}
```

it returns single letters of the first row. E.g, my first row is iPhone, the above command will loop through and log each letter as separate objects.

I'm thinking that I need to save each of the rows returned as a seperate array objects like device, device1, device2, device3, device4, because its saving over the device array name each time and only returning 1 result.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, turns out I needed to re-create the array in PHP. As usual if I retrieved an associative array from the database and echo'd it out, it would only echo the first row, unless i ran it through a loop.

The array was working, it was simply only returning 1 result. I changed my php to

```
 $getPhoneResults = $db->query("SQL QUERY GOES HERE");
 $newDeviceArray = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getPhoneResults)){
   $newDeviceArray[] = $row;
 };
 $url = $getSites['main_url'];
 $bounceRate = $getBounceRate['result'];
 $conversionRate = $getConversionRate['result'];
 $dataArray = array('url' => $url,'bounceRate' => $bounceRate, 'conversionRate' => $conversionRate);
 $results = array('dataArray' => $dataArray, 'phonesArray' => $newDeviceArray);
 echo json_encode($results, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

and now when I run

```
 console.log(result.phonesArray[0]);
```

It returns the row correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing what's actually in your `phoneArray` variable, but it looks a little suspicious that you're doing:

```
 var arrayLength = result.phonesArray.device.length;
```

Assuming (based on the name and that it's a result set from a database query) that the array you're trying to process is `phonesArray`, shouldn't this be:

```
 var arrayLength = result.phonesArray.length;
```

And then you'd access the members like:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     console.log(result.phonesArray[i].device);
 }
```

?

Comment: If i console log phones array length, it returns undefined, but if i console log the phonesArray.device.length instead, it returns the number of characters for the first row returned.

For example, it will return 6, because the first row is iPhone, which contains 6 characters

Comment: So phonesArray is not actually an array, then.  Have you tried `console.log(result)` to examine the data you're getting from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking the results from the database aka `$getPhoneResults` by doing something like:

```
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($getPhoneResults); die();
```

And then call the php-script directly from a browser.

If the result seems correct, then check the console for the entire result of the AJAX-call before you start to loop over it:

```
console.log(result);
```

For the loop, you could try doing this with jQuery instead:

```
$(result).each(function(i,e){
    //e.device
    //i will be your iterator
});
```

By the way...by adding:

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

To your php-script before outputting data, your response type will be correct and you won't have to do this:

```
$.parseJSON(results);
```

Hope it helps.